# Edit Bootstrap / CSS color

Tags: bootstrap-4, colors

today I bought a template for themeforest, modified the html index, and the last thing I need is to change the primary #007bff to #1d3557 blue color that bootstrap loads. I tried to override this color in the CSS style file, then in the bootstrap file. But once I upload the files to the web, bootstrap still shows the primary blue color, even I overwritten it in the files. Can someone please help me to change the color? Thanks for help.

CSS file
http://lifecoachingurbanek.site/soubory/style.css

Bootstrap file
http://lifecoachingurbanek.site/soubory/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

In the bootstrap file appears still `#007bff` instead of `#1d3557`. Try a search and replace all of `#007bff` with `#1d3557` in the `bootstrap.min.css` as well, that should work. For the colors, the `bootstrap.min.css` seems to have a higher priority than the style.css